# Сайдбар стилей в консоли Chrome съехал

Tags: google-chrome, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обрыл интернет и настройки, не могу передвинуть стили обратно вправо, сейчас они в отдельном блоке снизу. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Смешно что аж грустно.....нажмите на три точки, рядом с крестиком и будет выбор расположения панели

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так это всей панели, а он хочет половину панели переместить.

Comment: А оно в зависимости от ширины панели.. если больше делать, то сместится вправо, меньше - вниз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нажав на кнопку рядом с крестиком, можно увидеть следующее меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем можно выбрать способ расположения данного окна(слева направо):

1. отдельным окном
2. прикреплено снизу
3. прикреплено сбоку

При креплении сбоку, расположение элементов зависит от ширины данной панели.

Comment: Qwertiy говорит: "это всей панели, а он (ТС) хочет половину панели переместить"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там последняя строчка как раз поясняет

Comment: Мои комменты в ответ спер :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, :-Р это проверено опытным путем :-) так что не надо тут :):):)

Comment: Дело не в ширине а в масштабе как оказалось. но в любом случае ваш ответ навел на нужную мысль, спасибо.